# Cannot login to magento admin panel (was taking a backup)

Tags: magento, backup

I was taking a magento site backup today by going to admin->system->tools. I took the system backup first without any issues. Then I started database and media backup. But before the backup process could complete, I accidentally closed the tab in the browser.
After that i tried to login to admin panel and getting this error at the bottom of the page ->

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;
try restarting transaction' in /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php:64973 
Stack trace:
#0 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(64973): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(64561): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(53889): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54927): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `jdg_cor...', Array)
#5 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55785): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `jdg_cor...', Array)
#6 /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54044): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `jdg_cor...', Ar in /home/cellul82/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 64979
```

Can any one please help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error shows up as soon as i open the login screen for admin panel

Comment: You need to increase the innodb_lock_wait_timeout in the mysql configuration file and restart the mysql server